# How to get value of custom http header?

Tags: http

A custom created HTTP header whose value I need to fetch and for this, I am using following WordPress function

```
$response = wp_remote_get('http://example.com/page/');
$auth = wp_remote_retrieve_header( $response, 'Cache-Control' ); //Calling http header value of name "cach-control"
```

In above code, I am fetching a value of "Cache-Control" which is a default HTTP header. I know WordPress supports only limited HTTP header. I found one [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/http-headers/) that allow us to use more HTTP headers. But even with this plugin, I can't fetch the value of the custom created header.

Is there any way in which I can get the value of custom header?

Answer (score 2):

I checked `amazon.com` website for retrive `X-Amz-Cf-Id` header which I belive is not a standard header and for me it is working fine:

```
function wpse_288865_featch_header() {

    $response = wp_remote_get('https://www.amazon.com/');
    $custom_header = wp_remote_retrieve_header($response, 'X-Amz-Cf-Id');

    var_dump($custom_header);
    exit;
}

add_action('init', 'wpse_288865_featch_header');
```

Sometimes `amazon.com` is not returning this header so please refresh your WordPress site couple of times.

I also inspected WordPress core for parsing request and didn't found some kind of whitelist of headers. It is only removing [`transfer-encoding`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-requests.php#L672) and [`connection`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-requests.php#L679) headers.

Please check if you make proper request to your site. For the first time I have checked `google.com` and have similar issue. I couldn't get the headers which I've seen that `google.com` should return. Problem was that `google.com` do not allow me to make such a request and in return I get `HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden` response which obviously return completely different headers that `HTTP/1.1 200` response.

Comment: Ok after doing some more testing I found the real issue. In normal way it is working but when I send http header from outside the website i.e. from different domain then it don't fetch the http header. I tried your amazon http header and in normal it was working But when I tried to send it via Postman(chrom's extension) for testing purpose then didn't work.
In my case http header will come from outside of site that's why testing on postman. Any suggestion? For additional detail, I am using it on custom template file, not on functions.php So doing it without hooks.

Comment: What is in the `response` array? `$response['response']`? It should be `200`  code and `OK` message.

Comment: I made a custom template and put this in it `$response = wp_remote_get('https://www.amazon.com/');  $custom_header = wp_remote_retrieve_header($response, 'X-Amz-Cf-Id');`. When I do refresh page(in whch I attach this template) then it fetch header. But when I do this via postman then it don't fetch header.

Comment: To check if `$custom_header` is getting any value or not I am creating post with pending status like this (just for testing) `$my_post = array();
  $my_post['post_title'] = 'Post2';
  $my_post['post_content'] = $custom_header;
  $my_post['post_status'] = 'pending';
  $my_post['post_author'] = 1;
  wp_insert_post( $my_post ); ` And storing value of $custom_header in content of post.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know postman. Maybe this is problem of postman not WordPress or other site?